# POSIX: perror() - what does "MT-Safe race:stderr" mean?

Tags: posix

Please can someone help me to understand the POSIX safety concept, especially for `perror()`. The man page states that `perror()` is "MT-Safe race:stderr". As `perror()` outputs to standard error I would like understand what the given race condition means for the implementation.

Does this mean that output on `stderr` may be mixed, or are there other things someone must care about?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Conditionally-Safe-Features.html

Answer (score 2):

It means that `perror` writes into `stderr` and `stderr` is not thread-safe. The race condition means that you may get interleaved output if multiple threads write into `stderr` simultaneously.

[POSIX requires most functions to be thread-safe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09_01):

> All functions defined by this volume of POSIX.1-2017 shall be thread-safe, except that the following functions1 need not be thread-safe.

`perror` is not in that list.

Comment: Thanks. Interleaved output is acceptable for me (and what I have expected). This means stderr is not subject to race conditions which may crash my application. Right?